# Access parent prop / attribute from child component

Tags: javascript, attributes, reactjs, components

I have a component that looks like the code below and I need a way from within `SearchBox` to know the value of it's parent (`SearchContainer`) has the `withFilter` attribute set.

Even better if there's a way for `SearchContainer` to detect if it has a  `SearchFilter` component within it as well so I can get rid of that attribute and for `SearchBox` to know as well.

```
<SearchContainer withFilter>
    <SearchFilter>Filter Orders</SearchFilter>
    <SearchBox/>
</SearchContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a design approach, `SearchContainer` should have a prop that decides if it's showing `SearchFilter` or not.

```
var hasFilter = true;
return (
  <SearchContainer withFilter={hasFilter}>
      {withFilter ? <SearchFilter>Filter Orders</SearchFilter> : null}
      <SearchBox withFilter={hasFilter} />
  </SearchContainer>
);
```

You should use `this.props.withFilter` inside the `render` of `SearchContainer` in your code.

Comment: This is great, propagate all the props!